# Capturing Ctrl-X with the KeyDown event of a textbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to trigger an event when the user presses <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> using the `KeyDown` event. This works fine for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> but the event doesn't trigger when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> is pressed. I'm guessing this is because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> is the "cut" command. Is there any way to trigger an event when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> is pressed?

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.D:
                //handle D key
                break;
            case Key.X:
                //handle X key
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you handle the command rather than the event?

Comment: How would I do that, is there a way to override a TextBox's 'cut' command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the existing cut command:

```xml
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="X" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

You need to create a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) though.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get this to work in xaml (even created a dependancy property for the command) but it worked fine in code behind.

Comment: But a command usually operates at the viewmodel level, while copy functionality is spread to both code-behind and viewmodel. Infact if you allow reordering columns, you can't know the position of the columns from the viewmodel without violating MVVM.

Comment: @AgostinoX You either need to bind more information to the VM or if that is not possible, go through events in the view and then hand the information from the event to a VM command or method.

Comment: On the other hand, I found myself wondering if this is a case of view-only code. Let say that if the copy-paste operation is like an edit made by hand, why should the model be aware of it and handle it as a distinct operation?

Comment: @AgostinoX Sure, it depends on what the action is supposed to do.

Answer (score 26):

To do that in wpf I try this:

```
private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.X && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You press Ctrl+X :)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you wrote:
 if (e.Key == Key.X && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{
}
   
instead

 if (e.Key == Key.X && (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)) 
{
}

?

Comment: it is not going inside the 'if' statement for me. Any idea why?

Comment: @StepanIvanenko Because modifiers are flags and if you have multiple flags you can't get a match. He uses binary code to extract only the needed control flag.

Comment: @GeorgiG Which is not a good idea because usually keybindings should only trigger for an exact match, so in this case not for things like Ctrl+Alt+X.

Comment: I believe you can also check Control presence like this: ```e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.HasFlag(System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Control)```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers get the job done, but make debugging a pain.  Since CTRL is pressed first, it should be separated so it can be skipped and only checked by a single `if`.  The following should be efficient and easier to debug.

```
public MyApp() {
    // other constructor code
    KeyDown += MyApp_KeyDown;    
}

private void MyApp_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    // hold that CTRL key down all day... you'll never get in unless there's another key too. 
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key!=Key.LeftCtrl && e.Key != Key.RightCtrl) 
    {
        switch (e.Key) // <--- Put the BREAK here.  Stops iff there's another key too.
        {
            case Key.C: UndoRedoStack.InsertInUnDoRedoForCopy(CopyArgs); break;
            case Key.X: UndoRedoStack.InsertInUnDoRedoForCut(CutArgs); break;
            case Key.V: UndoRedoStack.InsertInUnDoRedoForPaste(PasteArgs); break;
            case Key.Y: UndoRedoStack.Redo(1); break;
            case Key.Z: UndoRedoStack.Undo(1); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this method:

```
private void SomeWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.X && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0)
    {
        //Ctrl + X is pressed
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try following in keydown event

```
       if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode==keys.x)
       {
            e.Handled = true;
            textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
            //Call your method
       }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the e object is the KeyEventArgs. This doesn't appear to have Control or KeyCode properties. See my edit above for the code. The event will fire for the 'ctrl' key but does not fire when the 'x' key is pressed while holding the 'ctrl' key

Comment: you added wpf after i posted my answer thats why some confusion