# Left CTRL + V Key not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I create a copy and paste code. For my current application, if I set Key.B instead of Key.V it works immediately. Key.V + Left CTRL doesn't fire. If I press Left Ctrl + Left alt + V with the code below, it works as well. I am so confused towards why Left Ctrl + V isn't firing. I created a blank WPF application and it fired fine. May I ask for tips on how to debug this situation. The code below resides within a UserControl.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e)
    if (e.Key == Key.V && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Paste Worked");
    }
}
```

If I set OnKeyUp, everything works fine!

Comment: OnKeyDown doesn't with any specific keys like Cntrl+A, Cntrl+Z. Probably those keys combinations directly overriden for standard wpf controls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072032/capturing-ctrl-x-with-the-keydown-event-of-a-textbox-in-wpf